# Which Version control system you would prefer for HTML, CSS, Javascript development for small team of Developers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, version-control, frontend

Which Version control system would be good for HTML, CSS, Javascript development for 4 Developers?

We are 4 developers, all in different countries and we all have different Operating systems. 2 Developers have Macbooks, one has Windows 7 and another one has Ubuntu 9 linux)

Some time on remote location we also do some changes in code using iphone and ipad using [FTP On The Go PRO](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ftp-on-the-go-pro/id364787363?mt=8)

And some time some place Internet is not available so we also work without internet.

I want to know the preferred Version control system for us which should be accessible from all devices and OSes. And should work offline too.
And how to setup for a project.

**Edit:**

I got this advice inside http://beanstalkapp.com/

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help you choose: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/77475/how-to-choose-between-git-and-mercurial

Answer (score 5):

My personal preference is [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).

We've used this on projects with a range of team members spanning 4 or more countries.

Mercurial is a distributed source control system which means that every developer will have their own repository on their machine and will push to a central location as and when possible (in your case, when an internet connection is available).

Given that this is the case it also makes it possible for developers to push/pull to/from one anothers machines over the network. Your collegue can make changes and you can pull them directly from his machine on the network.

Rob Connery also wrote an article about using Mercurial and the command line. It's a pretty good reference for the simple commands and explains the benefits of using the command line over a visual tool:

[Visual Tooling Will Make You Go Blind](https://web.archive.org/web/20100722030848/http://blog.wekeroad.com/2010/04/29/visual-tooling-will-make-you-go-blind)

Comment: Can we work offline and merge later in Mercurial after to get internet connectivity?

Comment: I would also recommend BitBucket (https://bitbucket.org/) for Mercurial source code hosting

Comment: @Jamnie - We already use Basecamp so someone suggested Git+ Basecamp + beanstalkapp. what do you think on this?

Comment: Pleas, update the web links. They looks being moved.

Answer (score 1):

[GIT](http://git-scm.com/) works well. You can have a GIT project on [GitHub](https://github.com), for example. It's free if the project is Open Source. GIT is a p2p version control system. Everybody has the whole commit history. You can synchronize the repositories when you have time...

Comment: As @Jamie wrote Mercurial has also the same functionality.

Comment: I would +1 for Git, but the answer is too vague and it implies that GitHub is the only place to host Git projects.

Comment: @Daniel Cassidy I fixed the second part of your comment (about GitHub) by adding "for example".