# Version Control for Javascript

Tags: version-control

What can be the best way to add vesrion control in javascript so that user will not need to clear cache and reload every time.

One possible way i found is to add version number at the end of url. Can there be other ways also?

Comment: Also, you can use CDN of jquery!!

Comment: may this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610602/which-version-control-system-you-would-prefer-for-html-css-javascript-developm